# Delphi Chromium Embedded CEF3: inspect element

Tags: delphi, dom, delphi-xe5, tchromium

I am using 2 TChromium components in my project. One to view my web project and one to view the developer tool associated.

When I view the developer tool and move my mouse over an element declaration, the corresponding dom elements is highlighted in my application but I cannot right click on a element of my web application and select the corresponding line on the developer tool.  can I inspect an element using the TChromium component like in Chrome?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TChromium  object does not expose the "inspect element" item in the context menu but it is possible to select dom elements using the magnifying glass in the developer tool.

Feel free to post a comment if you know how to expose the "inspect element" item in the context menu.